# How do I only load the body of a web page

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I want to add a UIWebView in my app but I only want to load the body of my webpage. I don't want the header or footer to show. How can I do this?

Comment: Make just the body of your webpage available when visited at a specific URL? (like, pass in some query parameter that returns only the body?)

Comment: In a UIWebView, instead of loading the entire web page, I only want to load the body of the webpage.

Comment: I don't think you can just change what is loaded. I think you need to have a url with only the body available.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this. You will need to detect which part of the web page is the body and grab it. This will require some algorithm work to do, and also the parsing of the web page content, not to mention if the web page contains invalid HTML tags, etc. Or even if the structure of the web page changes.

Or you can use Readibility API or other web service that will give you the content: http://www.readability.com/developers/api/reader#https://www.readability.com/api/rest/v1#articleRepresentation